# Unable to connect Apache kylin to superset

Tags: apache-superset, kylin

I'm running Superset on docker on windows, and kylin is runnning on another machine both are in same virtual network. I have installed kylinpy on docker container to enable connection from kylin on superset but I'm unable to connect. I'm getting following error:

```
(builtins.NoneType) None [SQL: _compose_select_body() takes 7 positional arguments but 9 were given] (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/dbapi)
```

SQLALCHEMY URI uri:

`kylin://ADMIN:KYLIN@<IP-address-machine-running-kylin>:7070/learn_kylin`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that sqlalchemy has been updated and it affects to the last stable version of kylinpy (2.8.4). But it also seems that the kylinpy team has solved this problem by adding some changes in [its code](https://github.com/Kyligence/kylinpy/pull/49). But there is not a new release for this, so you would have to install the current master branch. Try to install it with `pip install git+https://github.com/Kyligence/kylinpy.git@master`

Comment: Thanks, It is working now they have fixed it in kylinpy. If i execute pip install kylinpy its now working.